# Additional parameter in oauth2 token request

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, pkce

I'm developing backend for oauth2 client. I'm using authorization_grant flow with PKCE extension. I'm trying to implement it in such way that code verifier and code challenge is generated on clients side. So i have to add additional parameters to my token request (the second request, when input is authorization code and my application exchange it for access token). 
My app will have to take this code_verifier from request param and pass it to authorization server with authorization code, client id, and client secret.

So now I'm struggling with customizing spring-security-oauth2-client to add additional parameter. **There is way to add such parameters to authorization request by implementing OAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver, but is there analogical way for adding parameters to token request?**

Or maybe should i implement this endpoint manually?

Comment: What about adding this param to your token and getting it when decrypting your token !

Comment: This code verifier / code challenge is exanged before the token is created.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain, since Spring OAuth Security is often poorly documented for common use cases. One option you might consider is to provide a custom Spring filter that uses the open source [nimbusds libraries](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-oauth-openid-connect-sdk/examples/oauth/pkce), which have very good documentation and are easy to use.